# Good background music for a software demo?

Tags: background-music

I remember seeing some software applications demos before where they don't have any narration but just a background music played (no words, just the acoustic)...but i was never able to know the name of them. Any suggestions? It was pretty fast paced...or if you could kindly provide a link to some demo, I can try to search by voice...
Thanks

Comment: I've recommended this go to Programmers, but the question might be too off-topic and open-ended even for there.

Answer (score 1):

You might try http://www.ambientmusicgarden.com/. They have a lot of low-cost-royalty music which you can browse through based on several criteria. I first encountered them when the engineers at NASA did a really cool video montage of various launches and they used musci from there for their background.